# Test whether an IP is in Australia

Tags: php, ip-address

I need to do a quick server side test to check if an IP address is in or outside Australia.  I don't want t go to the lengths of querying a remote server nor that of maintaining a global IP address allocation table in my database.

In the past I have been able to get country-by-country IP allocation ranges from [apic.net](http://www.apnic.net/apnic-bin/ipv4-by-country.pl?country=au) but that URL does not seem to be valid anymore.  I would be surprised if it is longer possible to do this.  I would be much obliged to anyone who might be able to point me to the right location to get this information

Comment: You could try to understand the question or ask for clarification before you turn nasty.  I have writtten I do not want to maintain a GLOBAL IP allocation table - the implication being I want to maintain one just for Australia.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a downloadable country-wise listing [here](http://www.ipaddresslocation.org/ip_ranges/get_ranges.php).  As @Imane Fateh mentions the risk with relying on such resources is that they vanish one day.  That is why I had wanted to find a replacement for the one from apic.net that I mention in my original question (which was no insurance though given that it too has vanished :-()

Comment: Here is an interesting gotcha for anyone running into this thread. The PHP ip2long function returns different results on a 32 OS and a 64 bit OS. I have a 64 bit LAMP server but do most of my development on 32 bit WAMP. Converting the data from the link above on a 32 bit WAMP machine using ip2long would not work. So I did the conversion on my server, saved the results with a view to loading them into my local DB table via LOAD DATA INFILE.  Here is the gotcha - 32 bit MySQL can handle BIGINTs but LOAD DATA INFILE turns em all into signed 32 bit ints!. You need to INSERT each IP range pair!

Answer (score 1):

There's a downloadable address to country database (in csv format) available [here](http://software77.net/geo-ip/).  They also offer several programs and libraries to integrate that db in your application [here](http://software77.net/geoip-software.htm).

However, don't forget that these data are dynamic, and that you will have to update the database regularly:

> If you use our IP to country Database in your applications you should get an updated copy from time to time. Depending on your application, probably once a month should be fine. We have observed up to 50 row changes from a single registry in a one day on busy days. Some days there are far fewer.

Comment: Thanks for the tip on row changes - I have ended up using an AU specific downloaded table, see below, but I was not sure how often I should update it.

Answer (score 0):

You can find country-by-country IP allocation ranges in this site :
http://www.nirsoft.net/countryip/

But this site may not be valid for ever, so try to reconsider using locally/remote database.

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot implement your own ip geo-location, you can use this:

http://w3bdeveloper.com/api/geoIp/ip/24.24.24.24/key/hj2376bd2y8uhde27

Comment: Just clicked on it and it says I am in Germany, when I live in the US.

Comment: That is because the link he has given contains an IP address that IS in Germany!